# I want to make a batch file that will start a program and delete a specific folder after I exit the said program

Tags: batch-file, caching

So I want a batch file that will start my .exe and then when I exit the program it will delete the cache the program created.

So starting:

```
@echo off
start anything.exe
```

And after I exit the program I want: `rd /s /q "PortableData\Cache"`
in order to delete all file into the cache folder (is that correct?)

Still what code should I insert in order for the batch file to wait until I exit the program, to delete the cache?

Answer (score 0):

`start /?` will describe the features it supports, you want:

```
start /wait anything.exe
```

Comment: hank you, that worked. Is there a way for the batch file to hide itself (from display) until I am done using the program, when it will show again to delete the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use `/wait` argument for this:

```
@echo off
start /wait anything.exe
rd /s /q "PortableData\Cache"
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Is there a way for the batch file to hide itself (from display) until I am done using the program, when it will show again to delete the folder?